# Does information reach a quark with a radius instantaneously?

Tags: quantum-information, subatomic

In what sense do sub atomic particles have a size? Or are they better understood as points?

If a quark has a size, and a radius - would you expect that if an event happened to the left of a quark, the left side of the quark would receive information before the right side?

Similarly, if you think of particles as waves or distributed probabilities, does information reach a particle at once, or in a diffuse manner?

Comment: See this. [Is the zero distance limit of Coulomb's law something to worry about?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/453912/37364)